# Can I control the output directory for .d denpendency files for c++ project?

Tags: makefile, pgi

I have the following generic Makefile for my c++ project. I've recently shifted my compiler from GNU to PGI compiler, and found the dependency files are no longer stored in the BUILD_PATH, but in the SRC_PATH instead. Is there anyway I can save all of them to BUILD_PATH to keep my src folder clean?

```
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:$(SRC_PATH)/%.$(SRC_EXT)=$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o)
DEP = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

CPP_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -Wall -MD

.PHONY: default_target
default_target: release

.PHONY: release
release: dirs
    @$(MAKE) all

.PHONY: dirs
dirs:
    @echo "Creating directories"
    @mkdir -p $(dir $(OBJECTS))
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_PATH)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Deleting $(BIN_NAME) symlink"
    @$(RM) $(BIN_NAME)
    @echo "Deleting directories"
    @$(RM) -r $(BUILD_PATH)
    @$(RM) -r $(BIN_PATH)
    @$(RM) $(DEPS)

# checks the executable and symlinks to the output
.PHONY: all
all: $(BIN_PATH)/$(BIN_NAME)
    @echo "Making symlink: $(BIN_NAME) -> $<"
    @$(RM) $(BIN_NAME)
    @ln -s $(BIN_PATH)/$(BIN_NAME) $(BIN_NAME)

# Creation of the executable
$(BIN_PATH)/$(BIN_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking: $@"
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

# Add dependency files, if they exist
-include $(DEPS)

# Source file rules
# After the first compilation they will be joined with the rules from the
# dependency files to provide header dependencies
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.$(SRC_EXT)
    @echo "Compiling: $< -> $@"
    $(CXX) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LIBS)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PGI` compiler describe '-MD':

> -MD Generate a list of make dependencies and print them to the file file.d, where file is the root name of the file under compilation.

It does not offer any options to control location. Likewise, `GCC`:

> -MD -MD is equivalent to -M -MF file, except that -E is not implied.  The driver determines file
>      based on whether an -o option is given.  If it is, the driver uses its argument but with a
>          suffix of .d, otherwise it takes the name of the input file, removes any directory components
>          and suffix, and applies a .d suffix.

On surface, two options:

1. In the '%.o' rule, add a command to 'mv' the '.d', if created in SRC to the BUILD_PATH
2. Add explicit rule using '-M' and redirect stdout to the BUILD_PATH folder.

I think #1 is easier:

```
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.$(SRC_EXT)
    @echo "Compiling: $< -> $@"
    $(CXX) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(LFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LIBS) 
    [ -f "${^D}/$*.d" ] && mv -f "${^D}/${*}.d" "${@D}/" || true
```

Could not test with PGI compiler (no PGI compiler for me), so I hope it will actually work.